# Adding functionality for a date format of mmm dd, yyyy into existing function

Tags: javascript, date

I need your help,

How can I add existing functionality and build upon my existing function to also generate a dateformat of mmm dd, yyyy (ie. Feb 10, 2014)

So lets say for example: gatedate('testdate') generates: Feb 10, 2014

```
function getdate(type) {

    var today = new Date()
    var time = today.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/([\d]+:[\d]{2})(:[\d]{2})(.*)/, "$1$3")

    var dd = today.getDate()
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10){ dd='0'+dd }
    if(mm<10){ mm='0'+mm }

    today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy

    if (type === 'system') {

        return today +" "+time
    }

    else if (type === 'testdate') {

        return Feb 10, 2014
    }

    else {
        return today
    }

}//end function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this outside the function:

`var monthNames = ['Jan',Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];`

And then replace the contents of the `if` with:

`return monthNames[today.getMonth()] + ' ' + dd + ', ' + yyyy;`